# Shopify metafield json shown as table

Tags: json, shopify

I am new to this site and to json and I hope for your assistance.
We have a metafield that I would like to show as a table.

Json.Format is currently as follows:
"f3b77f84-9b4d-4740-b249-bf02c199695e": {
"type": "collapsible_text",
"settings": {
"title": "Eigenschaften",
"content": "

{{ product.metafields.custom.eigenschaften | metafield_tag }}</p>"

The number of lines per product might vary.

The final table should look like this as an example:

Properties
Attributes A:       123444
Attributes B:       789789
etc

I very much hope of any hints on how to solve it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Google research - unfortunately I could not find a hint.

Comment: Here [Link](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters/metafield-filters#metafield_tag) you can check which type of meta field generates which HMTL element using `metafield_tag`